# Quitar el encabezado HTTP Cache-Control de response en Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel-8, response, cabeceras-http

Estoy intentando devolver una respuesta en XML haciendo uso de la librería Laravel-XML (https://github.com/mtvbrianking/laravel-xml) y todo bien cuando utilizo este código en mis rutas en api.php:

```
Route::get('xml/{no_solicitud}.xml',function($no_solicitud){

$solicitud =App\Models\Solicitudes::all()->where('no_solicitud', $no_solicitud);
    
return $customXML;
});
```

Pero el problema está en que me devuelve algo así:

> 

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <Documento>
        <id_solicitud>1</id_solicitud>
        <llave>321</llave>
    </Documento>
    <Firma_Electronica></Firma_Electronica>
</document>
```

Con la etiqueta "document", la cual debo reemplazar por "Tramite". Así que lo que opte hacer fue utilizar str_replace() asi:

```
Route::get('xml/{no_solicitud}.xml',function($no_solicitud){

$solicitud =App\Models\Solicitudes::all()->where('no_solicitud', $no_solicitud);
$customXML = str_replace('document', 'Tramite', response()->xml(['Documento' => $solicitud->toArray(),
'Firma_Electronica' => '']));
    
return $customXML;
});
```

Y de inicio funciona pero devolviendome algo como lo siguiente:

```html
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  text/xml
Date:          Sun, 28 Nov 2021 01:19:50 GMT


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tramite>
    <Documento>
        <id_solicitud>1</id_solicitud>
        <llave>321</llave>
    </Documento>
    <Firma_Electronica></Firma_Electronica>
</Tramite>
```

Lo cual tiene esa cabecera, además ya no responde un xml sino un html me parece.
Ayuda, no encontré como quitar esa etiqueta desde la libreria, o si saben como quitar la etiqueta "document" o reemplazarla, me ayudarían. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el código de [XmlResponse.php](https://github.com/mtvbrianking/laravel-xml/blob/master/src/Http/XmlResponse.php) muestra que el tag  `document`, como nodo raíz, proviene de las opciones por defecto:

```
public $options = [
    'root' => 'document',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'version' => '1.0',
    'slug' => true,
];
```

En su constructor, dice que las opciones se pueden sobreescribir si acaso le pasas un arreglo de éstas.

```
public function __construct($data = null, $status = 200, $headers = [], $options = [])
{
    $this->headers = array_merge($this->headers, $headers);

    $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);

   ....
}
```

En el service provider de la librería se ve que la declaración del macro `xml` , que es lo que se ejecuta cuando haces `response()->xml(....)` es, como cabía suponer, una factoría que llama al constructor antes mencionado.

```
    Response::macro('xml', function ($data, $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = []) {
        return new XmlResponse($data, $status, $headers, $options);
    });
```

Por tanto lo que buscas se haría con

```
response()->xml(
   ['Documento' => $solicitud->toArray(),'Firma_Electronica' => ''],
   200,
   [], // no es necesario pasar headers 
   ['root'=>'Tramite']
);
```

Y que al instanciar una respuesta de ese tipo